# How to get the column names with value more than ZERO as the multilabels for each row

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, multilabel-classification

I have a case where I have label names as columns of a DataFrame with value 0 or more like below.

```
.net    2007    actionscript-3  activerecord    air ajax
0   0   0   0   1   1   1
1   0   0   0   1   1   1
2   0   0   0   1   1   1
3   2   2   2   2   0   0
4   2   2   2   2   0   0
5   2   2   2   2   0   0
```

My requirement is to put those column names whose value is more than zero, in a single column seperated by space for each row like below :

```
0   activerecord air ajax
1   activerecord air ajax
2   activerecord air ajax
3   .net 2007 actionscript-3 activerecord
4   .net 2007 actionscript-3 activerecord
5   .net 2007 actionscript-3 activerecord
```

Example : values in columns activerecord, air, ajax has value of 1 in first row so these 3 should appear in one column of the dataframe separated by space.

This is an example of multi-label classification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
print(df.apply(lambda x: " ".join([k for k, v in x.iteritems() if v]), axis=1))
```

output,

```
0                    activerecord air ajax
1                    activerecord air ajax
2                    activerecord air ajax
3    .net 2007 actionscript-3 activerecord
4    .net 2007 actionscript-3 activerecord
5    .net 2007 actionscript-3 activerecord
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sushanth.It works exactly like what's expected.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this using [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

```
df.apply(lambda x:' '.join(x.index[x!=0]) , axis=1)
```

Or
`df.T` is short hand for `df.transpose`

```
df.T.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.index[x!=0]))
```

Here's another hack: Using [`df.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) [`df.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) to find values not equal to 0 and drop `NaN` using [`df.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

```
df = df.stack()
(df.where(df!=0).dropna().reset_index().
    groupby('level_0')['level_1'].apply(','.join))

level_0
0                    activerecord,air,ajax
1                    activerecord,air,ajax
2                    activerecord,air,ajax
3    .net,2007,actionscript-3,activerecord
4    .net,2007,actionscript-3,activerecord
5    .net,2007,actionscript-3,activerecord
Name: level_1, dtype: object
```

Or
`df.groupby` allows to group by level and use [`pd.MultiIndex.get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html#pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values) to get level1 index values.

```
df = df.stack()
(df.where(df!=0).dropna().groupby(level=0).
    apply(lambda x:','.join(x.index.get_level_values(1))))

0                    activerecord,air,ajax
1                    activerecord,air,ajax
2                    activerecord,air,ajax
3    .net,2007,actionscript-3,activerecord
4    .net,2007,actionscript-3,activerecord
5    .net,2007,actionscript-3,activerecord
dtype: object
```